# Calculate the number of children in the below multidimensional array & update members count of the each parent

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, iteration

For the below multidimensional array, I was trying to increment the members of every parent child to their child + grand children + grand grand children + .... and so on, but my recursive loop gets stuck after few iterations. Please check below code and help me with improvements. Thank you in advance!

> Required Output should be like: **Member count of id = 100**, should be
>   **calculated to 9** & so on for every parent or child-as-parent

```
$t = array(
    array(
      "id" => 100,
      "member" => 3,
      "child" => array(
        array(
          "id" => 102,
          "member" => 1,
          "child" => array(
            array(
              "id" => 103,
              "member" => 1,
              "child" => array(
                array(
                  "id" => 109,
                  "member" => 1,
                  "child" => array()
                ),
                array(
                  "id" => 110,
                  "member" => 0,
                  "child" => array()
                )
              )
            ),
            array(
              "id" => 104,
              "member" => 0,
              "child" => array()
            )
          )
        ),
        array(
          "id" => 105,
          "member" => 1,
          "child" => array(
            array(
              "id" => 106,
              "member" => 0,
              "child" => array()
            )
          )
        ),
        array(
          "id" => 107,
          "member" => 1,
          "child" => array(
            array(
              "id" => 108,
              "member" => 0,
              "child" => array()
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );

  function test(&$array){
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      if(count($value['child']) == 0){
        if(array_key_exists($key, $array) == 1){
          $array[$key]['member'] = 0;
          continue;
        }
      }
      $array[$key]['member'] = count($value['child']) + count($value['child'][$key]['child']);
      test($array[$key]['child']);
    }
  }

  print_r(test($t));
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug it? Why didn't the loop finish, how far did it get?

Comment: its breaking at child of key 1 & key 2 of id 100...

0 Output: 100 has 3 child
0 Output: 102 has 2 child
0 Output: 103 has 2 child
0 Output: 109 has 0 child
1 Output: 110 has 0 child
1 Output: 104 has 0 child
1 Output: 105 has 1 child
Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/kumardeepak/public_html/Clients/disha/test.php on line 162
0 Output: 106 has 0 child
2 Output: 107 has 1 child
Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /home/kumardeepak/public_html/Clients/disha/test.php on line 162
0 Output: 108 has 0 child

@NicoHaase

Comment: And what have you tried to debug it? Have you read the two notices?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am telling, it breaks at grand child 106 of key 1 and gives the first notice & then breaks at grand child 108 and gives second notice... i tried to skip this by array_key_exists($key, $array) but it's not helping much... @NicoHaase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're not passing the member count of the children back up to the parent. You call the test() function on the children, but their result is never added to the parents member count. This will do the trick

(note that I call the function on `$t[0]` and save myself the additional loop within the `calc_children()` function - you probably want to loop over `$t` if you have more than one entry in that array)

```
function calc_children(&$parent)  {
    $parent['member'] = 0;
    if ($parent['child'])  {
        foreach($parent['child'] as $k => &$child)  { // make sure $child is a reference
            $parent['member']++; // count the child itself
            $parent['member'] += calc_children($child); // add the children of the child
        }
    }
    return $parent['member']; // return my members to my parent
}

calc_children($t[0]);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($t);
echo '</pre>';
```

As for your notice errors:
The issue is that you use the index `$key`of `$array` when you count the children of the child:

```
count($value['child'][$key]['child']);
```

`$key` is an index of `$array`, not of `$value['child']`

You'd need to do another loop on `$value['child']` to count its children.
Instead of

```
$array[$key]['member'] = count($value['child']) + count($value['child'][$key]['child']);
```

You'd need:

```
    $array[$key]['member'] = count($value['child']);
    if ($value['child'])  {
        foreach ($value['child'] as $child_key => $child_value) {
            $array[$key]['member'] += count($child_value['child']);
        }
    }
```

The result would still be wrong, though.